# failed to acquire lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager

Tags: kubernetes

i have deployed kubernetes cluster in a single bare metal based on [Kubernetes The Hard Way on Bare Metal](https://medium.com/@DrewViles/kubernetes-the-hard-way-on-bare-metal-vms-v1-23-2168f5fe70af) . the cluster unable to elect leader and found "failed to acquire lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager" error in kube-controller-manager.

```
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.400973    2037 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/vnd.kubernetes.proto>
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414148    2037 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: GetConnection 0 ms ServerProcessing 12 ms >
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414160    2037 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414166    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     Audit-Id: a9c5abd3-b307-4a33-a925-3b8595707639
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414171    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414174    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414178    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: b37cfda9-250f-476a-8a85>
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414182    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: d6696786-7e21-4dcc-a>
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414185    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 445
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414189    2037 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Tue, 02 May 2023 15:37:22 GMT
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414216    2037 request.go:1179] Response Body:
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000000  6b 38 73 00 0a 1f 0a 16  63 6f 6f 72 64 69 6e 61  |k8s.....coordina|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000010  74 69 6f 6e 2e 6b 38 73  2e 69 6f 2f 76 31 12 05  |tion.k8s.io/v1..|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000020  4c 65 61 73 65 12 91 03  0a b7 02 0a 17 6b 75 62  |Lease........kub|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000030  65 2d 63 6f 6e 74 72 6f  6c 6c 65 72 2d 6d 61 6e  |e-controller-man|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000040  61 67 65 72 12 00 1a 0b  6b 75 62 65 2d 73 79 73  |ager....kube-sys|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000050  74 65 6d 22 00 2a 24 31  38 63 62 38 65 33 65 2d  |tem".*$18cb8e3e-|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000060  33 33 36 63 2d 34 36 38  61 2d 39 64 61 64 2d 37  |336c-468a-9dad-7|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000070  66 34 35 34 61 65 37 63  30 65 33 32 06 31 36 36  |f454ae7c0e32.166|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000080  35 36 38 38 00 42 08 08  8c bf ed a1 06 10 00 7a  |5688.B.........z|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000090  00 8a 01 cd 01 0a 17 6b  75 62 65 2d 63 6f 6e 74  |.......kube-cont|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000a0  72 6f 6c 6c 65 72 2d 6d  61 6e 61 67 65 72 12 06  |roller-manager..|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000b0  55 70 64 61 74 65 1a 16  63 6f 6f 72 64 69 6e 61  |Update..coordina|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000c0  74 69 6f 6e 2e 6b 38 73  2e 69 6f 2f 76 31 22 08  |tion.k8s.io/v1".|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000d0  08 8c bf ed a1 06 10 00  32 08 46 69 65 6c 64 73  |........2.Fields|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000e0  56 31 3a 7c 0a 7a 7b 22  66 3a 73 70 65 63 22 3a  |V1:|.z{"f:spec":|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000000f0  7b 22 66 3a 61 63 71 75  69 72 65 54 69 6d 65 22  |{"f:acquireTime"|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000100  3a 7b 7d 2c 22 66 3a 68  6f 6c 64 65 72 49 64 65  |:{},"f:holderIde|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000110  6e 74 69 74 79 22 3a 7b  7d 2c 22 66 3a 6c 65 61  |ntity":{},"f:lea|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000120  73 65 44 75 72 61 74 69  6f 6e 53 65 63 6f 6e 64  |seDurationSecond|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000130  73 22 3a 7b 7d 2c 22 66  3a 6c 65 61 73 65 54 72  |s":{},"f:leaseTr|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000140  61 6e 73 69 74 69 6f 6e  73 22 3a 7b 7d 2c 22 66  |ansitions":{},"f|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000150  3a 72 65 6e 65 77 54 69  6d 65 22 3a 7b 7d 7d 7d  |:renewTime":{}}}|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000160  42 00 12 55 0a 33 6e 65  77 63 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c  |B..U.3newcontrol|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000170  6c 65 72 31 5f 62 34 66  63 64 35 66 38 2d 30 33  |ler1_b4fcd5f8-03|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000180  31 38 2d 34 37 65 61 2d  62 34 35 65 2d 66 62 66  |18-47ea-b45e-fbf|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 00000190  30 64 38 66 31 31 39 64  36 10 0f 1a 0c 08 82 fa  |0d8f119d6.......|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000001a0  a9 a2 06 10 bc b1 be be  01 22 0c 08 82 fa a9 a2  |........."......|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: 000001b0  06 10 bc b1 be be 01 28  0f 1a 00 22 00           |.......(...".|
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414263    2037 leaderelection.go:352] lock is held by newcontroller1_b4fcd5f8-0318-47ea-b45e-fbf0>
May 02 15:37:22 newcontroller1 kube-controller-manager[2037]: I0502 15:37:22.414270    2037 leaderelection.go:253] failed to acquire lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager
```

in the events logs, there are multiple retries to elect the leader.

```
k8s_baremetal$ kubectl get events --all-namespaces --kubeconfig configs/admin/admin-remote.kubeconfig
NAMESPACE     LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON           OBJECT                                          MESSAGE
kube-system   57m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_ca1bc253-4671-456a-a459-62b71d018c1f became leader
kube-system   56m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_35d87e32-4020-4d87-b08c-ae096d7359ac became leader
kube-system   54m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_e9ecef8c-059f-4ffb-8e0a-ee1c65d9e305 became leader
kube-system   52m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_c08e74c0-9b1f-4e98-91f8-01599326b513 became leader
kube-system   44m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_a0dd84db-1912-423a-b535-5ac2e00e6bf3 became leader
kube-system   40m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_19063e1c-025b-4211-9c55-259b8df579d2 became leader
kube-system   38m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller1_96fceaa9-376f-4dff-99b9-910280992327 became leader
kube-system   34m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller1_96fceaa9-376f-4dff-99b9-910280992327 stopped leading
kube-system   29m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_7f62c56e-ea30-4c02-baea-45243ad2b86b became leader
kube-system   27m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller1_52187a5e-b70d-4a71-b897-000b96cec01a became leader
kube-system   27m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller2_db778567-5fc1-4a3d-80a4-99a71d907547 became leader
kube-system   14m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-controller-manager                   newcontroller0_5e1181a3-9eee-4030-9369-a47c123fa13e became leader
kube-system   58m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_54d2fcba-ed08-4c52-b4f2-524d56871608 became leader
kube-system   58m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_54d2fcba-ed08-4c52-b4f2-524d56871608 stopped leading
kube-system   45m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_32d325da-ea18-4eb8-8b40-270d584192c3 became leader
kube-system   40m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_ca405285-608f-4c82-8b4f-ea2061cb03d1 became leader
kube-system   40m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_ca405285-608f-4c82-8b4f-ea2061cb03d1 stopped leading
kube-system   37m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller2_de20b407-f541-473e-aa43-2613d56bf5f7 became leader
kube-system   37m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller2_de20b407-f541-473e-aa43-2613d56bf5f7 stopped leading
kube-system   34m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller2_860e887d-f57c-4fa6-a258-3f6b65d2a3c0 became leader
kube-system   30m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller2_860e887d-f57c-4fa6-a258-3f6b65d2a3c0 stopped leading
kube-system   30m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_308eaa01-917d-4ecb-87cf-7875ceb99c27 became leader
kube-system   27m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller1_756293ba-2ed3-4024-994f-2dc3a724a19a became leader
kube-system   21m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_778f73e9-2147-4d0e-b969-2f961e2c9c0c became leader
kube-system   20m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_778f73e9-2147-4d0e-b969-2f961e2c9c0c stopped leading
kube-system   20m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_9a91d222-001d-4360-8b77-2867e901ff52 became leader
kube-system   19m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller1_29150ee7-749a-47ae-a44a-23fe917ef2c6 became leader
kube-system   12m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_ee93c6e5-fcc6-45d5-a657-f7f693a1ce91 became leader
kube-system   12m         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_ee93c6e5-fcc6-45d5-a657-f7f693a1ce91 stopped leading
kube-system   9m8s        Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_f325ce35-56b7-41f8-8559-bcf2dcbe5f79 became leader
kube-system   8m58s       Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_f325ce35-56b7-41f8-8559-bcf2dcbe5f79 stopped leading
kube-system   76s         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_bae43f5a-0ac5-4b09-aa63-6e00c4bb5b4b became leader
kube-system   66s         Normal    LeaderElection   lease/kube-scheduler                            newcontroller0_bae43f5a-0ac5-4b09-aa63-6e00c4bb5b4b stopped leading
```

in the bare metal, i created 7 VMs as described below using v1.23 kubernetes binaries.

```
controllers-lb 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (haproxy)
controller0 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (kubectl, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, etcd)
controller1 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (kubectl, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, etcd)
controller2 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (kubectl, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, etcd)
worker0 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (containerd, kubelet, kube-proxy)
worker1 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (containerd,kubelet, kube-proxy)
worker2 2 CPU 4096 MB RAM 6 GB disk (containerd, kubelet, kube-proxy)
```

i'm new to kubernetes and somehow puzzled on the error description in the logs. any help is appreciated.